# Adding dynamic fields to Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am just trying to add a simple text field for a title and have it posted to uploadify.php, but it's not working.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'formData'      : {"title": $("#title").val()},
        'swf'           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "title");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```

If I replace `{"title": $("#title").val()}` with `{"title": "title"}` it works fine but then it's not dynamic, it's just set to title. How can I get it passing the actual text field data? I've tried several things myself, but the Uploadify documentation is pretty thin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Uploadify documentation found [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/) says otherwise, but this seems to be the correct way to utilize dynamic fields with Uploadify. In any case, it works.

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'swf'           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", 'formData', {'title' : $("#title").val()});
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: It isn't required to have the formData declared in the first `$("#file_upload").uploadify()` so I removed it. Include it there as well if you want to use it to set default values.

Comment: This works this if you want to do it on the "onUploadStart". I think the documentation in Uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/ needs to be corrected? No?